# How to switch audio output between the two buds of headphones

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, core-audio, audio-route

My application demands a functionality that sound has to come through only one side of headphones based on the user choice. i.e either sound can play from left side of head phone or right side of the phone, but not from the two sides at a time.

I want to know that how to switch the audio output of an iOS device between the two sides/buds of the headphones connected to the device.How can i achieve this.Please share your suggestions and ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference) to play the audio, you can use the [pan](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/pan) property of the same to adjust the volume of each channel.

```
pan
The audio player’s stereo pan position.

@property float pan
Discussion
By setting this property you can position a sound in the stereo field. A value of –1.0 is full left, 0.0 is center, and 1.0 is full right.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
AVAudioPlayer.h
```

Or if you want more control over the audio playback, you can use AudioQueueServices described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/multimediapg/usingaudio/usingaudio.html), along with the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/oalTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007769).